# Is it possible to make a JSONP request from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, cross-domain, jsonp

I know there is an almost duplicate question, but the answer is not satisfactory at all.

I need to do geocoding using the Openstreetmap service which runs over HTTP.

My site runs over HTTPS.

It seems impossible to do JSONP request from https to http, browser (Chrome) complains about insecure content.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the browser complains about insecure content is that the content is insecure. The entire purpose with a secure page is that all of it is secure, and can be trusted.

You can set up a proxy page in your secure site that requests the insecure content. There you should verify the content before it's sent to the browser, so that it is actually secure, not just pretending to be secure.

Comment: So, in a real scenario, my JQuery should open a popup in http (only solution I can think for), get the JSONP response and parse it?

Comment: In a real scenario, you should not load content through unencrypted channels on a secure page. If you are not serious about security, just use HTTP in the first place.

Comment: @Cranio: No, the proxy that I am talking about is a page on the server. You make a https request to it, and it makes a http request to the service, verifies the response, and returns it to the browser.

Comment: @Tgr: not my fault, I *must* use https on my site and I *must* use an external service on FTP.

Comment: @Guffa: I figured out a method, added as an answer to myself. Feel free to comment

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a POST request to an external service that runs under HTTP while the initial request is coming from HTTPS it will always be considered as insecure.
There's, as far as I know, no way around it.

What you can do, is POST to your backend which send another POST request to the service that is running under HTTP. From there just return the value returned by the HTTP service.

Comment: You should **not** just return the value from the service, you should validate it first. The proxy is taking unsecure data and returning at secure data, so it has to take responsibility to check that it actually is secure.

Comment: In the end you probably want to return the data , if it is secure. Else there's no use in performing the request in the first place.

Comment: I said that you should validate it first. What do you think comes next? ;)

Answer (score 3):

For whom it may concern, this is how I sorted it out myself.

1) my Javascript code calls an AJAX page on my server with the parameter I need to forward to the service

2) the AJAX page makes a request via CURL using the address

3) I sanitize the response and turn it into JSON

4) with Javascript's callback-on-success I use the data

Comment: Yes, that looks good. The proxy page doesn't have to return the response unchanged.

Comment: @Guffa: yes, it's a pair of coordinates, very easy to sanitize via PHP. Thanks for helping :)