# JavaScript cross-domain call from HTTP to HTTPS any options

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, cors

I don't want to duplicate original question but I'd like to hear some options whether it's possible in general to make asynchronous call from HTTPS site to HTTP one.

It's important on my case because based on user location it will be determined to which real node request will go. So, option with additional proxy won't work (make call from application backend).

Option to manually turn of browser setting is not allowable.

Yeah in general it will be cross dpomain call and it will be good to hear some ideas whether it's feasible at all.

I saw number of threads where possible solutions are discussed:
- Use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211947/is-it-possible-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-https-to-http) and it was said that this is not possible to do; 
- Use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#user-agent-security) but as it was noted in documentation: https to http is not allowed. 
- use iframe or another workaround.

Any ideas under which browsers it's feasiblly to implement this ?

Comment: possible to use server-to-server call instead?

Comment: As I mentioned the main problem that  based on user location it will be determined to which real node request will go. AWS geolocation routing is in place,so it makes difference from what location call is done